# Error serialization exceeds the max collection object nest level of '25'

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, coldfusion

i have an Flex application which is using Coldfusion 10 as backend for manipulating data in a MySQL Database. Since some days I am getting intermittently errors in the Coldfusion logfile starting with:

### [BlazeDS] Error serialization exceeds the max collection object nest level of '25'.

flex.messaging.io.SerializationException: Error serialization exceeds the max collection object nest level of '25'.##

I tried to search Google, but didn't find any comments on that.

Is it possible to change the configuration, to set the maximum level to a value higher than 25 ? If it it is possible, does anybody know where I can arrange this in the Coldfusion configuration ?

Comment: 25 levels of nesting is a lot.  Maybe it's an indication that something needs improvement.

Comment: Agreed. Shot in the dark ... searching that error found this LC help file. It talks about services-config.xml which exists in CF too. Might be worth a shot if you can't refactor for some reason: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/CorrespondenceManagementSolution/WS05e11e68bd0645f37ab423091314e6366da-7ffa.2.html